# How do I convert a specific pixel width/height to media query in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, media-queries

I would like to know if there is a calculation method to find out how much should be given in a media query width/height if I want a certain widget to have a specific amount of height/width pixel count. I do know how to use media query but I don't quite understand how we provide the value 'x' below:

Example - width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / x (I need this to be 40 pixels, how is this calculated)

Please let me know, thanks in advance!

```
 Container(
                  // I need to know how would I calculate it for 40 pixels exactly using Media query
                  width: 40,
                  height: 40,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                )
```

Comment: check `MediaQueryData` official documentation - there is a property that is used for calculation physical pixels into logical pixels

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean the size property?

Comment: no, `size` is expressed in logical pixels

Comment: Is it the devicePixelRatio property that you are referring to.

Comment: yes indeed, doesn't it work?

Comment: Thank you so much for the start. I tried with (MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio * x [the required pixel amount]). Didn't seem to work.  Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: it's ok, what's the value of `devicePixelRatio`?

Comment: The value of it for my device is 4.0

Comment: so if your widget has for example `width: 100` it means that is is wide for 400 physical device pixels

Comment: So, for example, if I need a widget to have 100 logical pixels, Do I do it like so; width: MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio/100.

Comment: no, if you want your widget to be 100 logical pixels wide you set `width: 100` - it will be wide for 100 logical pixels or 400 physical pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use debugPrint(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width); to find out the screen size.  Then you can calculate

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried it with a formula, didn't seem to work. The question is, how can I calculate it by providing it the usual physical pixels? I need a formula.

Comment: If you want to 40px formula is: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-40)